# Distinguish between odd and even page in xsl

Tags: xml, xslt, dita

I have some table in my document and I want different margins for odd and even pages, so how can I distinguish a page is odd/even using when condition in xsl fo.

Answer (score 1):

You want:

- Separate `fo:simple-page-master` for the odd and even pages
- An `fo:layout-master-set` that selects the correct page master for odd and even pages. E.g.:

  ```
  <fo:page-sequence-master master-name="PageMaster">
    <fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
      <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="OddPage" odd-or-even="odd"/>
      <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="EvenPage" odd-or-even="even"/>
    </fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
  </fo:page-sequence-master>
  ```

  See https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#fo_page-sequence-master and https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#odd-or-even for more information.
- `master-reference` on your `fo:page-sequence` referring to the `fo:page-sequence-master`. E.g.:

  ```
  <fo:page-sequence master-reference="PageMaster">
  ```

Please also see the 'Switching between right and left page layouts' example PDF and FO in the 'XSL-FO Samples' page at https://www.antennahouse.com/xsl-fo-samples.  There are other `fo:page-sequence-master` samples on that page as well.